# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Field name expected in hive

Tags: json, hive

```
     While processing Json records in hive, getting the below error:-

 hive> select * from Json1_events_S3;
        OK
        Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Field name expected
        Time taken: 0.328 seconds
        hive> select count(*) from Json1_events_S3;
        Query ID = bdlm_20160818033736_2a3f3c20-5cc4-48f2-969e-6340307c2f8d
        Total jobs = 1
        Launching Job 1 out of 1`enter code here`
        Tez session was closed. Reopening...
        Session re-established.


        Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1470837272885_0976)

        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Map 1                 FAILED      1          0        0        1       4       0
    reducer 2             KILLED      1          0        0        1       0       0
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 17.90 s
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Status: Failed
        Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1470837272885_0976_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1470837272885_0976_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive

                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:543)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:83)
                ... 17 more
        Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Field name expected
                at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe.deserialize(JsonSerDe.java:183)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.readRow(MapOperator.java:143)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.access$200(MapOperator.java:107)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:534)
                ... 18 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Field name expected
                at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe.populateRecord(JsonSerDe.java:191)
                at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe.deserialize(JsonSerDe.java:174)
                ... 21 more
```

I have used json serde(ROW FORMAT SERDE'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe');to create the table and the same table is working fine for a smaller set of testing data.